# Custom form_for field accessible in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, attributes

I have custom field in `form_for`

```
check_box_tag "files_to_delete[]", :attach.id
```

Permitted params:

```
params.require(:post).permit( ... , :files_to_delete => [])
```

I have `before_action :some_method` in my model, in which i want to have access to the `files_to_delete`:

```
def some_method
  files_to_delete.each do |attach|
    attach.clear
  end
end
```

But i get:

```
undefined local variable or method `files_to_delete' for #<Post:0x007f5c4cb51ad0>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 1):

Your model needs a setter and getter for `files_to_delete`. Add the following line to your model:

```
attr_accessor :files_to_delete
```